# Ajax Post Request getting error as "status":415,"statusText":"Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am send post request using ajax call along the attachment(any file), but am getting error like "Unsupported Media Type" status code(415),

My code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#json').click(function () {
                alert('json');

            });

            $('#ajax').click(function () {

                var form1 = new FormData();
                form1.append("Test", "http://seekvectorlogo.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/opentext-vector-logo-small.png");

                $.ajax({
                    "async": true,
                    "crossDomain": true,
                    "url": RestApi,
                    "method": "POST",
                    "headers": {
                        "authorization": "Basic 12c3lzYWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQtMQ==",
                        "cache-control": "no-cache",
                        "postman-token": "2998576a-75d7-2f15-2f5a-84a8733df87a"
                    },
                    "processData": false,
                    //"contentType": false,
                    "contenttype": "multipart/form-data"`enter code here`,
                    "Content-Disposition": "form-data",
                    //"data": form1,
                    "data": JSON.stringify({
                        "file": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"
                    }),

                    success: function (result) {
                        alert("File available at: ", result);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        var obj = result;
                        console.log(obj);
                        alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
                    }
                });
            });
        });



    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <button id="ajax">ajax call</button>
    <button id="json">json</button>


</body>

</html>
```

The response should be a api as below:

> API/Attachments/78b8b5a579bd427f90f657a147e44ccd

Comment: For starters, remove `contenttype` - FormData has already taken care of preparing that correctly, and now you are invalidating it again (because yours doesn’t even include the boundary, that is necessary for this type of upload.)

Comment: Please take a moment to familiarise yourself with the code formatting tools - if HTML is not properly formatted, it will not be shown, or it will only be partially shown (as in this case). It is a good idea to proof-read your post after it is posted, so that you can edit it if it is does not appear as you intended.